# objective-C: Why interface type can't be statically allocated?

Tags: objective-c, interface

```
NSString s1;   //compile error: interface type cannot be statically allocated
NSString *s2   //good
```

Statically would mean the memory for that object is allocated at compile-time? But what is the reason behind allocating all objects at runtime and access through pointers?
I know that pointers allow a better use of memory, for example passing them as method's parameters but why forbid static allocation? I'm new to this language, I'd like to understand its vision.

Comment: use macros like `#define s1 @""` or `static NSString *s1 = @""`.

Comment: Turn your question around: what significant benefit would a programmer reap from the additional complexity that static allocation would add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++ you can't have polymorphic objects unless you have a pointer to that object.  Objective-C doesn't let you open that can of worms.  It's a dynamically typed language (with a lot of protection if you want) - and locking in your type at compile time goes against the philosophy of the language.

```
NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWith ???];
```

consider that line.  You're allocating a string object (I left the details of the constructor blank on purpose).  You won't get an actual instance of NSString - the type of your object will be a private subclass.  This concept is called Class Clusters.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

Depending on what constructor is run, and what parameters are passed in could affect what your runtime type is.  This would not be possible with a statically allocated object.

There is of course, a lot more to your question, but consider all that is possible given every object is dynamic at runtime.  Also consider the complexity of C++ that this avoids.

Comment: Great answer. Especially the comparison to C++.

Answer (score 1):

I bit about Objective-C. (The pointer world).

```
     // In Objective C, you work with pointers. And In fact you cast them in order to help the compiler help you.

NSString *s1;  // This means: hey compiler I expect s1 points to a NSString.
id s2; // id is the same like (anyKind *), It´s a pointer to an object, no matter how what kind.

// s1 and s2 are in fact the same;

// Try this:
NSArray *array = @[@"Understanding",@"Objective C"];

s2 = array;

s1 = s2;

NSLog(@"Let´s go to see s2 store object: %@",[s2 description]);


NSLog(@"Let´s go to see s1 store object: %@",[s1 description]);

// All work, because the type you declare is in order to help the compiler, this doesn´t have any effect a runtime.
// In fact, object has problem a runtime, If they receive a selector (methods) what they don´t know. In this case
// the selector sended is knowing for all kind of objects.

// If you change the order and assign first s1, the compiler could help you, and a warning there will be.
// Tomorrow more.
```